# Using Ruby on Windows Mobile Devices

Tags: ruby, windows-mobile, java-me, mobile

As far as I know, JRuby runs only on full JVM. I found [this version of JRuby](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/JRubyOnJavaMicroEdition) which runs on Java Micro Edition devices, however it's marked as *EXPERIMENTAL AND RESEARCH ONLY*

**Are there any other options for running Ruby *application* on Windows Mobile devices?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking.  Your title and your question refer to Ruby, but your description talks about JRuby.  Which are you asking about?

I know regular Ruby can run on Windows Mobile (see [Rhodes](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/12/rhodes-iphone-winmobile-rim), for example, or [RubyOnMobile](http://rubyonmobile.wordpress.com/)).

Comment: You may also be able to embed your Ruby app and a Ruby interpreter into a C-language program and compile it for WinMo (definitely not the easy route, however).

Comment: Which is basically how Rhodes works, not only on Windows Mobile but also the iPhone.